# Sharepoint: disable inheritance of metadata columns in folder structure

Tags: metadata, inheritance, subfolders, break-inheritance, parent-child

It seems that in whichever subfolder/parent folder I create new columns with metadata, these colomns are also shown in each parent and subfolder. Can I disable this behaviour so that each level in the folder structure can have it's own metadata set (= columns)?

Answer (score 1):

Library columns are not specific to a folder and are available at all folder levels of the library. You can however restrict the use of columns by using content types. Content types can represent all sorts of content including types of document and folders.

[Introduction to content types and content type publishing](https://support.microsoft.com/office/introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-e1277a2e-a1e8-4473-9126-91a0647766e5)

Comment: Thanks, I just found out also. I'm wondering: can I specify a content type for every hierarcy level of the folderstructure separately, or for each subfolder separately, with each content type having it's own set of metadata columns?

Comment: Generally this isn't possible but it might be possible using Document Sets (Document Sets are a type of folder). Previously, you were able to define "Allowed Content Types" for a document set. The limitation of Document Sets, is that you can't have Document Sets inside of other Document Sets.

Comment: I see. That's a pitty. I would not know why one would like the same metadata structure in each folder actually.

Comment: It's probably nog even possible to adjust the view for each folder separately? That could be a solution, kind of.

Comment: You can create separate libraries for different purposes, each library can have their own columns/views.

Comment: True that, document sets does the trick apparently.